# how to form a framework in selenium driver for web automation where by just passing some metadata, the entire code must be generated

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, frameworks

I need knowledge about how to develop a framework for web automation using selenium webdriver. please give me ideas and steps to create framework.
Now I'm able to locate all the web elements on web application by just writing a one big bunch of TestNG test code by using @Test annotation.
In my web application there are many places where I can reuse the code to do the same operation across all. So help me out to develop a best framework.

Comment: ,Google it, there are bunch of videos on youtube regrading different kind of automation frameworks.

Comment: I need a base idea to develop a framework and how framework generates code? :(

Comment: again, you can google it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the problems you are facing.

If you want to clearly separate writing scenarios from editing the logic (for instance, you work in a team with testers who aren't software engineers but know Java and algorithmic well enough to construct elaborate scenarios from small building blocks), then it would be wise to introduce a layer of steps classes containing methods like openTheUserMenu(), fillTheFormDetails(String name, String surname, String address) etc.

If you write tests for some dynamically changing or developing project with UI elements changed or refactored often you would definitely need Page Object pattern to encapsulate the UI logic (so that in your steps you would write just mainPage.selectDateOnCalendar(Date date), and all the necessary typing and clicking would be written out in the page's method).

Finally, if you work closely with your client and need to formulate the requirements in natural language first, and then translate them into more formalized language for developers to implement the required functionality, you would need to use BDD and appropriate libraries like JBehave with scenarios written in phrases in high-level almost natural language mapped onto test methods in Java.

In short, this is it. If you want details, there are plenty of materials on the Net as was mentioned already. Just remember - you should invest in elaborate framework only if you really need one to solve the problems you are facing.

Comment: Thank you soo much for giving me some basic tips and idea! I would try doing what you said..